# How to set version number to java web application using maven?

Tags: maven, build, version, bamboo

I need send build number via http response to the front-end from my web java application. But what's the best and correct way to set it at a build time? I'm using maven on bamboo. I know I can [pass version number to maven](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO011/1.2.1+Using+Custom+Variables). But I'm not sure about next steps. I only think about executing ant from maven, writing version to property file from ant, and reading it using resources from java app. Please, give some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would include your version number as part of the *manifest.mf*. If you plan to use a SVN revision (or any other SCM, you'd just need to find equivalent plugins) as a version number, you can use the [maven-svn-revision-number-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-revision-number-plugin/) along with the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

Here is an example on how to use it with SVN:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>svn-revision-number-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <entries>
            <entry>
                <prefix>scm</prefix>
            </entry>
        </entries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <SCM-Revision>${scm.revision}</SCM-Revision>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then to read it from your Controller/Servlet:

```
ServletContext application = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
InputStream inputStream = application.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
String value = attr.getValue("SCM-Revision");
```

Answer (score 10):

I see no problem with making a version file (we use this approach in our projects). If you know you'll have some property (f.e. `${build.version}`) at build time, you can use filtering to achieve your goal.

1) Create version file under `src/main/resources` with the following content

```
Version: ${build.version}
```

2) Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

3) Build the project. Filtered version file should appear in `target/classes`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/), which will set `${buildNumber}` property, which you can write to `MANIFEST.MF` like this (if it's WAR):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, you can read it using [java.util.jar.Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html) class. Take a look at how we do it in [jcabi-manifests](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html). Here is a real life example (we are using Git): [pom.xml](https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth/blob/master/s3auth-rest/pom.xml). The application is deployed to Heroku: [www.s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com). You can see the revision number in the right bottom corner of the web page.